# combining static and dynamic polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I want to apply the same implementation to different interfaces which seems to lend itself to static polymorphism:

```
template <typename T>
class HexAttribute
{
public:
     T* GetValue();
     void AddToValue(const T& valueToAdd);
     std::wstring* GetName();
private:
    T* value;
    std::wstring* name;
};
```

However, in the end I want to end up with all my HexAttributes in a single collection as a member of my Hex class:

```
class Hex
{ 
std::vector<HexAttribute*> attributes;
};
```

My question is how to collect a, say, `HexAttribute<int>` along with a `HexAttribute<float>` & `HexAttribute<foo>` into the same collection? I do not know all the different types I'll need yet.

Typically, I see dynamic polymorphism being used in the form of an abstract base class that all the HexAttribute would derive from and use a 
`std::vector<IHexAttribute*> attributes;`

But dynamic polymorphism usually lends itself to different implementations of the same interface which doesn't fit my situation well.

Is that the best way to go? Usually when I hit difficulties like this I find there's a much more elegant and simple solution someone's already thought of. Any thoughts?

Comment: Never forget `;` at the end of class declaration! After a decade of C++ programming, this is the first thing I spot without even reading the code ;-)

Comment: How are you planning to use an element in the vector without dynamic polymorphism?  (This isn't necessarily a rhetorical question - it might clarify an appropriate solution.)

Comment: @happydave - yeah, my only idea is to create an ABC (`IAttribute`) for the vector and derive HexAttribute<> from it so I can cast it later for use. It's just that that's the only reason I have for needing the dynamic poly here. I have no need to create different implantations of any virtual methods this ABC might have (the main reason for ABCs), almost like the ABC is a dummy class just for the sole purpose of handling a cast... leading me to question if I'm going down a poor design path.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<HexAttribute*> attributes;` is invalid, because `HexAttribute` with no template parameter is not a type.

You can define Hex as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Hex
{ 
    std::vector<HexAttribute<T> > attributes;
};
```

Then we can use it like: `Hex<int> int_vec`; or `Hex<float> float_vec`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I know it's invalid hence my question and the concept of `IHexAttribute`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it's invalid hence my question. That's why I'm contemplating the concept of `IHexAttribute` after that snippet. A Hex<??> would limit my Hex object to only having attributes that operate on a single type and I need my Hex object to have attributes that operate on more than one arbitrary types.